# Execution order between React's useEffect and DOM event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, web-storage

I wrote a custom context provider in the below which holds application settings as a `Context` as well as save it in `localStorage` (thanks to a [post](https://medium.com/@akrush95/global-cached-state-in-react-using-hooks-context-and-local-storage-166eacf8ab46) by Alex Krush).

I added `initialized` flag to avoid saving the value fetched from `localStorage` right after the component is mounted (`useEffect` will be run at the timing of `componentDidMount` and try to write the fetched value to the storage).

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useReducer, useRef } from 'react';

const storageKey = 'name';
const defaultValue = 'John Doe';

const initializer = (initialValue) => localStorage.getItem(storageKey) || initialValue;
const reducer = (value, newValue) => newValue;

const CachedContext = React.createContext();

const CachedContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue, initializer);
  const initialized = useRef(false);

  // save the updated value as a side-effect
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized.current) {
      localStorage.setItem(storageKey, value);
    } else {
      initialized.current = true; // skip saving for the first time
    }
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <CachedContext.Provider value={[value, setValue]}>
      {props.children}
    </CachedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```js
const App = (props) => {
  return <CachedContextProvider><Name name='Jane Doe' /></CachedContextProvider>;
}

const Name = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useContext(CachedContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(props.name);
  }, [props.name]);
}
```

Then, I'd like to make my custom context detect changes to the target storage made by another window. I added `handleStorageEvent` to `CachedContextProvider` for listening storage events:

```js
  // re-initialize when the storage has been modified by another window
  const handleStorageEvent = useCallback((e) => {
    if (e.key === storageKey) {
      initialized.current = false; // <-- is it safe???
      setValue(initializer(defaultValue));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageEvent);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageEvent);
      };    
    }
  }, []);
```

My concern is *whether I can reset `initialized` to `false` safely* for avoid writing back the fetched value. I'm worried about the following case in the multi-process setting:

1. Window 1 runs `setValue('Harry Potter')`
2. Window 2 runs `setValue('Harry Potter')`
3. Window 2 runs `localStorage.setItem` in response to update on `value`
4. `handleStorageEvent` in Window 1 detects the change in storage and re-initialize its `initialized` and `value` as `false` and `'Harry Potter'`
5. Window 1 try to run `localStorage.setItem`, but it does nothing because `value` is already set as `'Harry Potter'` by Window 2 and React may judge there is no changes. As a result, `initialized` will be kept as `false`
6. Window 1 runs `setValue('Ron Weasley')`. It updates `value` but *does not save it* because `initialized === false`. It has a chance to lose the value set by the application

I think it is related to the execution order between React's `useEffect` and DOM event handler. Does anyone know how to do it right?

Comment: Have you tried or is it speculation there could be an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is just a speculation. But I think it should be the case if `useEffect` is NOT dispatched atomically right after `setValue` is called (in other words, if the event handlers can be interleaved with the React hooks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed the problem with my colleague and finally found a solution. He pointed out that new React Fiber engine should not ensure the order of execution of side-effects, and suggested adding a *revision number* to the state.

Here is an example. The incremented `revision` will always invoke `useEffect` even if the set `value` is not changed. Subscribers obtain `state.value` from `Provider` and don't need to concern about the underlying `revision`.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useReducer, useRef } from 'react';

const storageKey = 'name';
const defaultValue = 'John Doe';

const orDefault(value) = (value) =>
  (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) ? value : defaultValue;

const initializer = (arg) => ({
  value: orDefault(localStorage.getItem(storageKey)),
  revision: 0,
});

const reducer = (state, newValue) => ({
  value: newValue,
  revision: state.revision + 1,
});

const useCachedValue = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(reducer, null, initializer);
  const initialized = useRef(false);

  // save the updated value as a side-effect
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized.current) {
      localStorage.setItem(storageKey, state.value);
    } else {
      // skip saving just after the (re-)initialization
      initialized.current = true;
    }
  }, [state]);

  // re-initialize when the storage has been modified by another window
  const handleStorageEvent = useCallback((e) => {
    if (e.key === null || e.key === storageKey) {
      initialized.current = false;
      setState(orDefault(e.newValue));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageEvent);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageEvent);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return [state.value, setState];
};

const Context = React.createContext();

const Provider = (props) => {
  const cachedValue = useCachedValue();
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={cachedValue}>
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add some sort of test to see what happens in every possible scenario.

However, this is my theory: In step 5, window 1 will not try to run localStorage.setItem (as you said), since initialized was just set to false. It will instead set initialized to true. Step 6 should therefore work as expected, and this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried React does not run `useEffect` because `value` is already `'Harry Potter'` in Step 4 and Step 5 can be skipped by React (`value === 'Harry Potter'`). If React runs Step 5 anyway, it may not be an issue as you said.

Comment: Oh shoot. There is an issue. You're right. You could perhaps solve that by also keeping initialized in a state so that the effect is re-executed when initialized is changed?

Comment: Yes, your solution is not optimal but acceptable (every storage change events trigger to read a value and write it back again for every window listening the key). If exists, I'd like to see some technical document mentioning around the React's execution strategy to know what I want do is feasible or not.