# building useLocalStorage Hook to allow the storage of a Set variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, state

I tried to modify the code found here > [useLocalStorage hook](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/)

so that I could save a Set() to localStorage.

**useLocalStorage.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Hook
export const useLocalStorage = (key, initialValue) => {
  // State to store our value
  // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
      return initialValue;
    }
    
    try {
      // Get from local storage by key
      const item = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
      // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
      if(initialValue instanceof Set) {
          return (item ? new Set([...item]) : initialValue);
      } else {
        return item ? item : initialValue
      }

    } catch (error) {
      // If error also return initialValue
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });

  // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
  // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
  //const addValue = (value) => {
  //    setStoredValue(prev => new Set(prev).add(value));
  //};

  // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
  // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
      const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      if(valueToStore instanceof Set){
        setStoredValue( new Set([...valueToStore]) );
      } else {
        setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      }
      // Save state
    } catch (error) {
      // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Save to local storage
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        if(storedValue instanceof Set){
          window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify([...storedValue])); 
        } else {
          window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(storedValue));
        }
    }
  }, [storedValue]);

  return [storedValue, setValue /*,addValue */];
}
```

in my React Component I'm trying to set the value based on the previous state.

**reactComponent.js**

```
const [itemUrlIdSet, setItemUrlIdSet] = useLocalStorage('itemUrlIdSet', new Set());
const addItemUrlIdToSet = (item) => setItemUrlIdSet(prev => new Set(prev).add(item));

useEffect(() =>
    addItemUrlIdToSet(`text changes when props change`);
}, [props]);
```

if I replace the setValue with addValue, it works fine... the Set in storedValue state updates, and the localStorage updates. If I use setValue, the storedValue never actually changes.

Add is less than ideal, there will be times I need to replace my Set() with a completely new Set() not based on the previous Set().

I'm stumped as to why it's not working with setValue. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) instead of setting the `value` directly?

```js
setStoredValue((prev) => new Set([...valueToStore]))
```

Note: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62197608/1014818) is my solution to the problem.

Comment: I tried this, it did not work on its own. I posted an answer above with what I did that did work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out. In reactComponent.js I adjusted my code like this >

```
const addItemUrlIdToSet = (item) => setItemUrlIdSet(prev => new Set(prev).add(item));
```

to this

```
const addItemUrlIdToSet = (item) => setItemUrlIdSet(prev => prev.add(item));
```

I think whats happening is the reference to the Set() was not updating the State inside the hook. I know usually you should not directly mutate the state like this. I am unsure if there is a better way. but its working.

Edit: I also added the modification that @okapies suggested, in useLocalStorage.js

```
    setStoredValue((prev) => new Set([...valueToStore]) );
```